# Is the newInstance method fast with little footprint to use in PHP 8 ReflectionAttribute class?

Tags: php, php-8

In PHP 8, the class ReflectionAttribute is introduced. It is something like annotations in Java, Typescripts and etc. Well every time you wanna use the attribute of a property, for example, you must do as follow:

```php
$attributeReflection = ...;
...
$attribute = $attributeReflection->newInstance();
$message = $attribute->getMessage();
```

Where the $attributeReflection is an instance of ReflectionAttribute. And the attribute itself is as follow:

```php
#[Attribute(Attribute::ALL)]
class MyAttribute{
    public function __construct(
        public ?string $message = ''
    ){}
}
```

And is used as follow for a property

```php
class Foo{
    #[MyAttribute("my message")
    public ?string $id = null;
}
```

As you can see, every time I wanna get the message of the attribute, I have to create a new instance of it. While the message is never changed for this case.

I`m looking for a way to avoid a new instance and use a shared one.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like nobody has written up the documentation for the `ReflectionAttribute` class yet, but you can see [a summary in the feature proposal for Attributes](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/attributes_v2#reflection), which lists its methods:

```php
class ReflectionAttribute
{
    public function getName(): string { ... }
    public function getArguments(): array { ... }
    public function newInstance(): object { ... }
}
```

The key here is that you can access the arguments *without* calling the constructor - indeed, the attribute name doesn't even need to be a valid class name, since it will not be autoloaded until `newInstance` is called.

So in your example, you can simply say `$message = $attributeReflection->getArguments()[0]`, or write a custom factory that merges instances with the same message, etc.

On the other hand, beware of premature optimisation: only spend time making this more complex if profiling tells you that this is actually a significant cost in your application. You may well find that the reflection itself has a much higher cost than this constructor call, and decide to run the whole thing in a build script, saving the information needed at run-time into some kind of cache.